# .net ef core - How to set a relation to a compsite key and does my table design make sense at all?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, .net-core

Im not sure how I need to set the relations between a table with a Unique Key to a table with a composite key. I want to do this with .net Entity Framework Core but I guess it is a sqlserver db design problem in the first place.

I have a table that holds text in different languages with a composite key (ID, CultureCode)
**Table: Shorttext**
Column: ID (PK)
Column: CultureCode (PK)
Column: Text

I have multiple tables which should have a reference to the Shorttext table. As a example this could be
**Table: Webpage**
Column: ID (PK)
Column: NameShorttextID
Column: DescriptionShorttextID
an other not relevant columns.

or as an example many other tables like
**RandomOtherTable**
Column: ID (PK)
Column: ContentShorttextID
an other not relevant columns.

Finally I would like to query like this but form within .net core

```sql
SELECT w.ID, st1.Text as Name, st2.Text as Description
FROM Webpage w
JOIN Shorttext st1 on st1.ID = w.NameShorttextID and st1.CultureCode = 'en'
JOIN Shorttext st2 on st2.ID = w.DescriptionShorttextID and st2.CultureCode = 'en'
```

So far this works. **But here is my biggest question**: From the database design should these tables not have a relationship between each other???

I guess **NameShorttextID** (table Webpage) and **DescriptionShorttextID** (table Webpage) somehow need to have a relation to the ID of the table Shorttext. The same applies for the **ContentShorttextID** (table RandomOtherTable). But this does not work, since I cannot set a reference from a composite Primary key (ID,CultureCode) to a single column (ForeignKey) like NameShorttextID, or can I? Or does a reference beween the table not make any sence?

So I thought I would do it the other way around and as an example set the column NameShorttextID as Unique Key and set a relation to the ID (table Shorttext). This has worked with the code below but I guess it does not make any sense since I cannot add values to the table Shorttext anymore because of all ist relations.

I tried it with this:

```cs
public class Webpage
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NameShorttextID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DescriptionShorttextID { get; set; }
}

public class RandomOtherTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ContentShorttextID { get; set; }
}

// composite key
modelBuilder.Entity<Shorttext>()
            .HasKey(s => new { s.ID, s.CultureCode });

modelBuilder.Entity<Webpage>()
            .HasOne<Shorttext>()
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Shorttext>(s => s.ID)
            .HasPrincipalKey<Webpage>(w => w.NameShorttextID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<Webpage>()
            .HasOne<Shorttext>()
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Shorttext>(s => s.ID)
            .HasPrincipalKey<Webpage>(w => w.DescriptionShorttextID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<RandomOtherTable>()
            .HasOne<Shorttext>()
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Shorttext>(s => s.ID)
            .HasPrincipalKey<RandomOtherTable>(w2 => w2.ContentShorttextID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

// Prevents the creation of a unique ForeignKey ID, must only be unique with ID, CultureCode (composite key)
modelBuilder.Entity<Shorttext>()
            .HasIndex(w => w.ID)
            .IsUnique(false);
```

Well, tecnically the code above works but I guess it makes no sence at the end.

Here to sum up my questions again:
- Does the table Shorttext need to have a relationship to all the other tables from a database design view?
- If the relation do make sence then how would you create them with ef core?
- If you would not set relations between the tables how can I make it easy in .net core (ef/linq) to query/update/add data without navigation properties?

I would really appreciate if anyone could bring some light into this because right know I am pretty confused...thank you!!!

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization

Comment: Tables (bases, views & query results) represent relation(ship)s/associations. FKs are sometimes called "relationships" but they are not. They say that subrows appear elsewhere as a PK/UNIQUE. Table meanings are necessary & sufficient to query. Constraints--including CKs, PKs & FKs-- are not needed to query. They are consequences of the table relation(ship)/association choices & what situations/states can arise. They are for integrity to be enforced by the DBMS. PS Please ask one question per post. Yours seem all basic faqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two tables.  One with PK of ShortTextID and a child table with the different translations.

```
create table ShortText(Id int primary key)

create table ShortTextTranslations
(
  ShortTextID int not null references ShortText,
  CultureCode varchar(10) not null references Cultures,
  Text nvarchar(max),
  constraint pk_ShortTextTranslations primary key (ShortTextID, CultureCode)
)
```